# Parametrizing inside class

Tags: python, pytest

Let's say I have a function which takes in a string and returns the first 5 characters:

```py
def crop_string(x):
    return x[0:5]
```

For example:

```py
>>> print(crop_string("hello world"))
hello
```

Now say I want to test this function. The contents of the test module could be as follows:

```py
baseline = "hello"
longer = "hello world"
even_longer = "hello world!"

@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "input_string, expected_result",
    [
        (baseline, baseline),
        (longer, baseline),
        (even_longer, baseline),
    ],
)
def test_crop_string(input_string, expected_result):
    assert crop_string(input_string) == expected_result
```

Which would run fine.

Now suppose this would be part of a larger test module with more functions. It seems to be that there might be a benefit in placing these tests inside a class, as follows:

```py
class TestCropString:

    baseline = "hello"
    longer = "hello world"
    even_longer = "hello world!"

    @pytest.mark.parametrize(
        "input_string, expected_result",
        [
            (baseline, baseline),
            (longer, baseline),
            (even_longer, baseline),
        ],
    )
    def test_crop_string(input_string, expected_result):
        assert crop_string(input_string) == expected_result
```

This gives me an error: `In test_crop_string: function uses no argument 'input_string'`.

So I have 2 questions:

1. What is a "good practice" way to "pass" the test parameters (`baseline`, `longer`, `even_longer`) to enable the tests to run.
2. Would there be any benefit in defining these test parameters inside a fixture, for example possibly as follows?

```py
@pytest.fixture
def setup_test_data():
    baseline = "hello"
    longer = "hello world"
    even_longer = "hello world!"

    return baseline, longer, even_longer
```

(This was a bit of a silly example but hopefully is sufficient to explain my question).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As decorators are evaluated at load time, you cannot use class variables there, as the class is not known at load time. That means that you have to define your parameters either inline or outside the class.

What is often done is defining the parameters in a global function:

```py
def get_params():
    baseline = "hello"
    longer = "hello world"
    even_longer = "hello world!"
    return [
        (baseline, baseline),
        (longer, baseline),
        (even_longer, baseline)
    ]

...
    @pytest.mark.parametrize("input_string, expected_result", get_params())
    def test_crop_string(self, test_data):
        ...
```

This avoids at least the use of global variables in this case.

Regarding the decorator: you also cannot use a fixture inside the decorator. You can use a parametrized fixture, but that only makes sense if you want to use the same parameters in several test methods in your class:

```py
@pytest.fixture(params=get_params())
def test_data(request):
    return request.param
 
class class TestCropString:

    def test_crop_string(self, test_data):
        assert crop_string(test_data[0]) == test_data[1]
```

If you want to apply the same parameters to all test methods in the class, you can put the `mark.paramtrize` decorator on the class instead.

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize("input_string, expected_result", get_params())
class TestCropString:

    def test_crop_string(input_string, expected_result):
        assert crop_string(input_string) == expected_result
```